# How to get max_element from vector<std::string>

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, max

Using the code from  [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/), I am trying to find the max int value in an `vector<std::string>`.
the vector is in std::string format and there is no choice here.

```
bool myfn(int i, int j)
{
    return i < j;
}

vector<std::string> dat;
dat.push_back(2.1);
dat.push_back(5.3);

for (int l = 0; l < dat.size(); ++l)
{
    std::cout << *std::max_element(dat.begin(), dat.end(), myfn) << '\n';
}
```

expected output:

```
3
```

error:

```
.cpp:76:93: error: no matching function for call to 'max_element(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::size_type, bool (&)(int, int))'
```

How do you find the max value in a `vector<std::string>`?

Comment: `myfn` is completely unnecessary. The default is to do less than.

Comment: Your loop is useless. `max_element` will go over the entire range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your std::vector dat declaration is wrong as you want to push_back int.
std::max_element and std::min_element returns an iterator not value. You can have a look into the following example

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v {1,2,3,4,6};
    auto biggest = std::max_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
    std::cout << "Max element is " << *biggest
       << " at position " << std::distance(std::begin(v), biggest) << std::endl;

    auto smallest = std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
    std::cout << "min element is " << *smallest
        << " at position " << std::distance(std::begin(v), smallest) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get an exception, probably because your vector is int, mine is string. Is there a simple function to convert to double (these are long decimals) on the fly?

Comment: You need to change the data type as double if you want to work with double. This is simple as std::vector<double> v {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,6.0};

Comment: The data comes in as strings (no choice). I need a double value returned.

Comment: how do you do that to a vector? I have endless data.

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `max_element` with the wrong arguments. It takes two iterators and a function:

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class Compare>
ForwardIterator max_element (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
                           Compare comp);
```

You're calling it with a vector and a size. The confusion might stem from the example on the reference you link where they do:

```
std::min_element(myints,  myints +7,  myfn)
//               ^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^
//                int*       int*
```

In this case, both `myints` and `myints + 7` are of type `int*`, and a raw pointer is an iterator. In your case however, you are passing two *different* types (`vector<string>` and `size_t`), *neither* of which is an iterator. So you need to instead do:

```
*std::max_element(dat.begin(), dat.end(), myfn)
```

Or, to illustrate something equivalent to the example in the reference (although definitely prefer the above):

```
std::string* first = &dat[0];
*std::max_element(first, first + dat.size(), myfn)
```

Which works because in this case I am passing two `string*`'s, which are iterators.

(Also based on your usage, `dat` should be `vector<int>` not `vector<string>`.)

Comment: adding the template and changing .begin and .end, it now throws this error  https://bpaste.net/show/f869abf55eea

Comment: @nerd007 Your `myfn` function still takes two integers as parameters when your vector's elements are of type `std::string`. If you change the parameter type to `std::string` your error will go away, but the default comparison `max_element` uses is `<` so `myfn` isn't even needed.

Comment: the question was std::string max_element because the vector is std::string (no choice here) and when I try and convert it to std::double, I drop a digit, so my math will be wrong. Your code does not work because it is for int, not std::string vector.   :(

Comment: @nerd007 You have to pick a type. You declare `vector<string> dat`, but then `dat.push_back(1)`... `1` is not a `string`. And your comparator function, `myfn`, takes two `int`s, not two `string`s. Everything has to be the same type.

Comment: the data comes from the www as a string. those strings fill a std::string vector. Once they are there, I need the max value (the top pick). Yes, there is a conversion required here. www won't throw doubles to me. no choice on the data type, I have to work with what I got.

Answer (score 2):

You have a vector that is full of strings `vector<std::string> dat;` but yet your comparison functions takes 2 integers. You might want to either change the type that is stored in the vector or change the comparison function you use. If you use integers then the default comparison operator will do what you want already without you needing to write a custom function.

Also [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) expects to get iterators one for the start and one for the end, so you need to change your call to be something like `std::max_element(dat.begin(), dat.end(), myfn)`. You might notice that the loop you have is actually not needed because you already go over that range with the call to `std::max_element` all this loop does is compute the exact same value multiple times, you only need to compute it once.

Comment: how do you insert a long decimal (double) in string format into a double vector?

Comment: @nerd007 you would want to use something like std::stod http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/

Comment: @nerd007, also this is starting to feel like it could be a XY problem, what would be an example input you would use? Please supply a verbatim example, it would help.

Comment: I have a vector that fills with strings (no choice) not double. I need to know the double value of the max element. There is a conversion that needs to happen here.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers can be iterators. This is what allows you to use arrays as a range in standard library functions. `myints` is an expression that refers to the first element of the array, and `myints + 7` refers to one past the end of the array. Equivalently you can do `std::begin(myints)` and `std::end(myints)`. Standard containers expose iterators in the form of these member functions `myvector.begin()` and `myvector.end()`. You pass these iterators, not the container and size, to `std::max_element`.

By default, `std::max_element` uses `operator<` to compare the elements. You don't need a comparator functor in this instance.

Your `std::vector`'s `value_type` is `std::string`, but you're trying to pass an `int`. Either change the `value_type` to int, or use a string conversion function, i.e. C++11's `std::to_string`.

Finally, your loop is completely unnecessary. `std::max_element` operators over a range.

```
std::vector<int> dat; 
dat.push_back(1); 
dat.push_back(3);

std::cout << *std::max_element(dat.begin(), dat.end()) << '\n';
```

Comment: The data is in std::string format. not int. In the end it will need to be in double format. but I am given std::string.

Comment: ***The data is in std::string format. not int*** Well then you should not be providing a comparison function that takes int should you? You need a comparison function that takes strings.